# Chrome autocomplete only first word in URL-bar

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Is there a hotkey combination in Chrome to autocomplete only the first word from the suggestion?

E.g.

**Input:** jqu

**Suggested:** jquery search multiple classes

**What I want:** autocomplete to jquery and write e.g. " cdn" -> hitting enter should search for "jquery cdn"